# Image processing using java

Tags: java, image, rotation, chunks

I am writing a java code that divides an image into chunks and rotate to some degree and combine the chunks to become one final image. Then use same code to divide the image into chunks and rotate opposite. I expect to get the same image as the original but I get an image with black line separated between them. For example an image is divided into 8 rows and 8 columns and conduct rotation. I have googled it and come up with the following code:

```
    public static BufferedImage Didvide( BufferedImage image , int Bz ,double       angle ){    
int rows = Bz;
int cols = Bz;
int chunks = rows * cols;
int chunkWidth = image.getWidth() / cols;
int chunkHeight = image.getHeight() / rows;
int count = 0;
BufferedImage imgs[] = new BufferedImage[chunks];

for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++) {
        imgs[count] = new BufferedImage(chunkWidth, chunkHeight,
                image.getType());

        // draws image chunk
        Graphics2D gr = imgs[count++].createGraphics();
        gr.drawImage(image, 0, 0, chunkWidth, chunkHeight, chunkWidth
                * y, chunkHeight * x, chunkWidth * y + chunkWidth,
                chunkHeight * x + chunkHeight, null);
        gr.dispose();
    }
}

BufferedImage[] Rimgs = new BufferedImage[imgs.length];
for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    Rimgs[i] = rotate(imgs[i], angle);
}

chunkWidth = Rimgs[0].getWidth();
chunkHeight = Rimgs[0].getHeight();

// Initializing the final image
BufferedImage finalImg = new BufferedImage(chunkWidth * cols,
        chunkHeight * rows, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

int num = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        finalImg.createGraphics().drawImage(Rimgs[num], chunkWidth * j,
                chunkHeight * i, null);
        num++;
    } }   return finalImg; }


         public static BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage image, double angle) {
    double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle)), cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));
    int w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight();
    int neww = (int) Math.floor(w * cos + h * sin), newh = (int) Math
            .floor(h * cos + w * sin);
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = getDefaultConfiguration();
    BufferedImage result = gc.createCompatibleImage(neww, newh,
            Transparency.OPAQUE);
    Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();
    g.translate((neww - w) / 2, (newh - h) / 2);
    g.rotate(angle, w / 2, h / 2);
    g.drawRenderedImage(image, null);
    g.dispose();
    return result;
}
```

The problem I face after dividing an image of baboo gray-scale 298X298 pixel into 8 col and 8 row, the resulting image has black lines separating columns. However when I divide the image into 12 or 4 it works fine. Can you please let me know where I should consider.

Seems I can not post image. 
When I divide and rotate the image into 8 rows and 8 columns of an image with 298X298, I get a result of 296X296 pixel. How can I fix this. So the size of before dividing and rotating is same as after.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you show us the result and what you expected ?

Comment: Seems I can not post images :) .